How to cut hole in pocket door near frame when door is closed, for installation of lock
I'm trying to easily cut a hole in the pocket door while it's closed, to install a pocket door lock.
The lock needs to go at the end of the door, it's very close to the frame which makes for difficult cutting since the frame adds a couple inches of space between a potential cutting blade and the cutting tool.
I've tried using a drywall knife but it's to difficult to get a clean rectangular cut. I was thinking about a Dremel but I'm not sure if the blade length would be long enough to compensate for the closeness to the pocket door frame. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Which end is the square hole to be near?  If the door is about half open, is this the side that is still in the wall or, the visible side you can grab onto.  The locks I see on Amazon would require a square hole at the edge of the door you can grab when it's half open.  Is that what you are wanting to cut a square hole into?

The lock I purchased is a metal rectangle that one half pushes into the hole I'm trying to cut and the other half protrudes to hit the frame so somebody tries to open the door on the outside, they're unsuccessful

The lock is flush with the door when not in use

The lock is only visible if the door is completely closed

"I've tried using a drywall knife" Er, the right tool for the job! Do you have any chisels? If you don't have any chisels they are still THE recommendation, but with caveats — they'll need to be sharpened, and that means you need to get sharpening gear as well, but also need to learn how to do it. This is not a simple ask for most first-timers, and may actually be impossible...... even with the wealth of sharpening guidance available online because reading/seeing good instruction is absolutely not the same as doing (it's not rare for people to struggle with sharpening for a Very Long Time).

I don't prep, cut, drill, chisel, rout, and install hardware on an installed pocket door.

You're more than likely to have to move the trim because of the new hardware.
Trim is meant to be removed. It's trim.
Stabilizing an installed door to work on it does not support accuracy and safety.
Uninstalling and reinstalling the door is faster in the long run.

I’ve never met a pocket door kit I liked or that didn’t have problems across a hundred or so kits for a project.
I’ve installed a couple of hundred of these things in large commercial construction projects for high-end condos as well as SROs and each one is finicky.
Please take this to heart: measure twice, cut once. Construction is math.
Round latches are easier than square. Just saying.
Survey everything you see and use a tape measure you trust. Write everything down. Draw a picture if you have to.
Determine if the door is hollow core, solid core, or wood slab.
In my opinion, hollow core and solid core doors must have a manufacturer installed wood block at the elevation from the top of the door that is the height from the floor, when door is installed, that you want your latch to locate. Measuring from the top is more consistent than from the bottom of the door because floors and bottom rail off cuts are inconsistent.
If your door is solid core or hollow core without a wood block at latch set elevation then remove the door and replace with appropriate wood slab pocket door a manufactured one with a wood block.
There’s a technical term in construction: poultry fecal matter.
Trying to install a latch set into a hollow core pocket door without a wood block results in poultry fecal matter.
Trying to cut a neat and clean layout in some composite doors may result in frayed cardboard that looks like poultry fecal matter.
Trying to modify an existing pocket door by installing your own planed, and cut to fit wood block may also result in poultry fecal matter.
Lets assume you have the proper door that either has a wood block at the correct elevation or a wood slab.
Remove the trim from the split jamb (2ea) and top rail fascia (2ea) which hides the track the door slides on. But first, cut the paint at the seams with a utility knife to reduce damage. Gently use two painter’s pry bars and a 5 in 1 painters tool.
Push the door all the way into the pocket and measure the gap (reveal) on each side of the split jamb without trim.
Look at the specs of the latch you have bought. Determine if the latch set is flush or surface mounted.
Decide if the play of the door with the latch set installed will bind inside the pocket when the door, trim, and frame swell and shrink with the weather. Or buy the appropriate latch set to fit your conditions without binding.
If you’re ok with what you have measured and thought it through mark your center line for the latch set at the elevation that works with your conditions on the door on the leading edge (latch side), wrap it around both sides, and the corresponding strike side of the pocket door frame.
Remove floor guides.
Remove the door per top track specs.
Layout the latch on the door according to the manufacturer.
Layout the strike on the door frame according to the manufacturer. Confirm your layout is accurate in three dimensions and correct to the back set of the latch.
Score all lines first with a utility knife. Cut away from corners, not towards.
Sharpen your chisels.
Use chisels for clean bits. You can use paddle bits for rough bits.
If you want to use a trim router and buy or make the appropriate jig. I have never thought dremels were a good idea.
Test your jig on wood scraps to confirm you’re good.
I imagine the corners of the leading edge of the pocket door will be the most delicate for latch prep. The wood block makes a big difference.
Install latch and strike.
Hang door.
Make sure the door rolls into the strike side and is flush and works with the strike. Use a machine file by hand to alleviate any binding of the latch on the strike.
Reinstall floor guides.
Reinstall trim to confirm it will not bind on the latch trim. Remember, wood expands and shrinks with humidity. What is easy when it's dry may be stuck when the humidity is high.
Fill your old and new trim nail holes.
Primer and paint.
Good luck.

The trim isn't the problem, it's the fact that the pocket door is installed. I'm going to end up removing the door so it's easier to work on. Thanks again for all of your tips. I do measure twice and cut once. I'm also aware that construction is a lot of math. If I could upload pictures, it would make life easier for all involved
